# Determine if a linear transformation exists between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If I am given example vectors $ \mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c $ and $ \mathbf r, \mathbf s, \mathbf t $, how can I find if there exists a linear transformation such that

$$ \mathbf T \mathbf a = \mathbf r $$
$$ \mathbf T \mathbf b = \mathbf s $$
$$ \mathbf T \mathbf c = \mathbf t $$

The vectors can be in any dimension space $ \Bbb R ^n $ where $ n = 1,2,3,4... $

Is there a general formula/method to determine this? $ \mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c, \mathbf r, \mathbf s, \mathbf t $ is not necessarily different. For example, if $ \mathbf a = \mathbf b $ and $ \mathbf r \neq \mathbf s $, we can instantly know that $ \mathbf T $ does not exist.

Is there a general method or series of steps to determine this?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are independent, then $T$ exists.  If not, any dependence relationship among $a,b,c$ must also hold among $r,s,t$ for $T$ to exist (this is necessary and sufficient).

Comment: So the question becomes how can find if any same dependence relationship holds between a,b,c and r,s,t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a $T$ exists if and only if the following 3 statements are true:

1. If $a=0$, then $r=0$.
2. If $b = ka$ for some constant $k$, then $s=kr$.
3. If $c = ma+nb$ for some constants $m$ and $n$, then $t=mr+ns$.